# Sort on function applied to each item in array element in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an object that contains a field with a list of measures for one of the fields:

```
public class TestObject {

    [BsonElement("graph")]
    public List<Measurement> Graph { get; set; }
}

public class Measurement {

    [BsonRequired]
    [BsonElement("magnitude")]
    public uint Magnitude { get; set; }

    [BsonRequired]
    [BsonElement("measured_on")]
    public DateTime MeasuredOn { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to write a find operation for MongoDB that would retrieve the first N `TestObject` entries ordered by the sum of the M most recent `Magnitude` attributes on the `Graph` attribute. My current attempt looks like this:

```
var findOptions = new FindOptions<TestObject> {
    Limit = N,
    Sort = new SortDefinitionBuilder<TestObject>()
               .Descending(p => p.Graph.OrderByDescending(r => r.MeasuredOn)
               .Take(M)
               .Sum(r => r.Magnitude)),
    Projection = new ProjectionDefinitionBuilder<TestObject>()
                     .Slice(p => p.Graph, 0, N),
};

IMongoCollection<TestObject> collection = GetCollection();
var cursor = await collection.FindAsync(FilterDefinition<TestObject>.Empty,
                                       findOptions, 
                                       token)
                             .ConfigureAwait(false);
return await cursor.ToListAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

However, this is currently throwing a `NotSupportedException`:

```
System.NotSupportedException: 
The method OrderByDescending is not supported in the expression tree: 
{document}{graph}.OrderByDescending(r => r.MeasuredOn).
```

From this I can understand that my attempt to mix LINQ expressions with MongoDB will not work, but I can't figure out how to make this query work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't think it's possible to achieve with the `Find` interface. however, the `Aggregation` interface can do it like so:

```
let docLimit = 1;
let graphLimit = 2;

db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 1,
                graph: 1
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$graph"
        },
        {
            $sort: { "graph.measured_on": -1 }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$_id",
                graph: { $push: "$graph" },
            }
        },
        {
            $set: { graph: { $slice: ["$graph", graphLimit] } }
        },
        {
            $set: { graphSum: { $sum: "$graph.magnitude" } }
        },
        {
            $sort: { graphSum: -1 }
        },
        {
            $limit: docLimit
        },
        {
            $unset: "graphSum"
        }
    ])
```

also don't think you can translate the above aggregation query to a strongly-typed c# query either. you'll just have to pass a json string to the driver.

Comment: I was hoping I would be able to avoid aggregations but I can see your point. However, the aggregation you provided doesn't appear to work. It doesn't limit the number of entries in the `graph` attribute and it doesn't sort the entries in the `graph` attribute by date.

Comment: `$sort: { "graph.measured_on": -1 }` sorts the graph items by descending date. then it limits entries with `$set: { graph: { $slice: ["$graph", graphLimit] } }`. have a look at the mongoplayground sample data. when sorted by date, the magnitudes will be [40,30,20] for the first doc and [30,20,10] for 2nd doc. and after limiting to the top 2 entries, they become [40,30] and [30,20] and when summed they become [70] and [50]. when that gets sorted and limited by 1, the result is the doc that had 70 which is the first doc. maybe i misunderstood your requirement. what is your expected output?

Comment: I did check it out your mongoplayground link and that's where my feedback came from. I changed the magnitude on one of the measurements on the second item to 70 and it didn't appear first in the list. Furthermore, the date sorting doesn't work. IT appears to work because the input was already sorted.

Comment: @Woody1193 https://mongoplayground.net/p/IFJ3SxbOVhK works for me. i changed the second magnitude of the 2nd doc to 50. it now returns the 2nd doc as expected.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I had to deconstruct it and build it up myself to see what it was doing. Yes, it does work. The only problem is that the sorting and filtering is supposed to remain in the returned data.

Comment: I made edits to your answer to fit the requirements I had. It was correct, just the output wasn't quite what I needed and I'm sorry I didn't realize it.

Comment: @Woody1193 i edited the query to get rid of that lookup stage which is not really needed. if you have other fields you need included just add them to the initial project stage.